# how to populate input on div click and live search with ajax js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax live search that calls php file and searches mysql. Everything works, you can start typing in the input field and you'll get results back live. I wanted to add pre-defined phrases user can search. You click on a div that contains the word, word shows up in the input field aaaaand.... nothing happens until I click on the input field and either press enter or add a letter or remove a letter.

How can I make the search show results live after just clicking on a the div? Without having to additionally click on the input field and press enter...?

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg search-terms"
                            placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">

<div class="grid-layout" id="list"></div>

<div class="slist">
<div class="symbols"><span class='badge badge-pill badge-secondary text-lowercase'>search phrase</span></div></div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.symbols').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#search');
        text.val(text.val() + $(this).text());
        
         });
            $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
                $("#.symbols").html("");
                var search_query = $(this).val();
                if (search_query != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "search.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            search: search_query
                        },
                        success: function($data) {
                            $("#list").fadeIn('fast').html($data);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#list").fadeOut();
                }
            });
            
        });
        </script>
```

I'm mostly a php guy and somehow js and ajax goes over my head :/ I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can seperate ajax call to another function and than call it with both click div and key up function.. Dont forget to send value of inside element to new funcion...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
  const iAmAjaxFunction = (event) => {
    $(".symbols").html("");
    $("#result").html("I am prof of done" + event);
  }
        
  $('.symbols').on('click', function () {
    const text = $('#search');
    const value = text.val() + $(this).text();
    text.val(value);
    iAmAjaxFunction(value)
  });
         
         
  $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var search_query = $(this).val();
    iAmAjaxFunction(search_query)
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg search-terms" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">

<div class="grid-layout" id="list"></div>

<div class="slist">
<div class="symbols"><span class='badge badge-pill badge-secondary text-lowercase'>search phrase</span></div></div>


<div id="result">aaa</div>


</html>
```